# Calculating overlapping between different datasets using R

Tags: r, overlap

I have 49 datasets which include different values like this.

```
inPUT=read.table(file="TEST.csv", sep=",", header=T, row.names=1)
class(inPUT) 
[1] "data.frame" 
length(inPUT) 
[1] 49 
head(inPUT) 
GO.1  GO.2  ...  GO.49
1 811 811 ...  811
2 813 814 ...  814
3 814 819 ...  817

length(inPUT$GO.1) 
[1]191 
length(inPUT$GO.49) 
[1]170
```

I'd like to calculate overlap between two different datasets among total 49 datasets (all possible pairwise calculation). Is there any R package to calculate how two sets overlap (I'm still new but..). Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data? Are you sure about the data structure?

Answer (score 3):

Is it so that every dataset only represents one column, as in your example?

One possible option is to use the '%in%' operator function, e.g.

```
mean(GO.1 %in% GO.2)
```

will tell you the percentage of observation in GO.1 are also present in GO.2. If you want to calculate the total overlap, you could use it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer` to compute pairwise combinations, and `intersect` to find the members that are in both sets. So something like:

```
outer(inPUT, inPUT, intersect)
```

may help.